# CSS Flex element is overflowing the page even though the container is not

Tags: css

I have been working on this for a
while and cannot figure out
why the chat box is going outside
the screen when zooming in / out.

Here is the chat box before zooming.

[image: Chat box is in the normal position]

Below is the chat box after zooming in a bit.  It goes off the
bottom of the screen making it impossible for the users to type in it.

[image: Chat box pushed off screen]

I am using Flex to position the elements.  ( CSS below )
I was under the impression that using **flex: 1;** show make
the flex element take up the remaining space,  which it does
but in some cases it overflows outside the screen even though
the container is never bigger than the view port.

Why would this happen?

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#top-panel {
    display: flex;
    height: 38pt;
    width: 100vw;
}

#content-holder {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
}


#chat-holder {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Where the chat-holder is inside of the content-holder.

The general layout looks like below.
[image]

Comment: can you add the html code?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that here because this is a very large project.  ( 20,000 + lines )